# How to test top-level React component managing state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have shallow render tests for all my Components that use just props. Some of them are Stateless functional like FB defines them, some of them are standard extended Components but without state.

Shallow is just great for these components. Very fast and I found a nice way to test that callbacks are passed properly as well without re-rendering.

Anyways - since I had to use rather big parent component that controls state and sets props for child (tested) components - now I have to test the parent component.

Note that this is part of legacy Rails app and currently I cannot use Redux. But I'm considering converting all parent component state manipulating methods (aka addTodo) to pure functions that will accept state as an argument etc.

What's the best practice to test this "parent" component:

1. Use shallow render again and just make sure that top-level methods (aka addTodo) are passed correctly to child components. Then test if the top-level methods return correct new state - they have to be pure because it seems I cannot access state when using shallow.
2. Use shallow render like in #1 but to test top-level methods use callback methods to actually call them, then rerender and test if the new "tree" contains new todo etc.
3. Resort back to DOM and Simulate for this component.
4. ...

Thanks.